# When I run this code I get a Nameerror when a user enters an name on line 9

Tags: python

I get a name error whenever I run this.

```
import random

intHigh = 0
strName = ""
strLevel = ""
intRandom = 0
boolAgain = "yes"

strName = input("What is your name? ")
```

Comment: What version of Python? This runs in Python 3. I think you are running this in Python 2. Which means you should be using `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: What actually you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, and `input()` tries to run the input as a Python expression, and `raw_input()` will return a string.

And in Python3 `raw_input()` is renamed to `input()`, and `input()` is gone.

So you can try to use `raw_input` instead of `input`, or use python3.